# Can I require a one-to-one relationship in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I've got a Product class and a Detail class.  I wanted to separate the big, long description from the basic data (sku, price) just for speed.  However there will always be a big long description.  So each item in the store will always have two records.

Is there a way to force or require both records?  Is there a way to require that the 1-to-1 relationship exists - so that this would always work...

```
$P = new App\Product(['sku'=>'123','price'=>69]);
$P->Detail->html = '<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>';
$P->push();
```

My hasOne/belongsTo stuff is all fine.  But if the details record does not exist yet ~ I get errors.  I'm wondering if Detail can auto-magically exist.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot you can do to 'force' the paired record to exist, however you could use a getter to make the retrieval of the description a little safer. Something like:

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function detail()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Detail');
    }

    public function getDetailHtml()
    {
        if ($this->detail()->count()) {
            return $this->detail->html;
        }
    }
}
```